# the structure of a phrase

Tags: structure

I cant understand the structure (and meaning) of the bold part. Is it right? is it possible to paraphrase it in an easier way?

Why is bad behaviour such a concern to parents? Why does this issue
motivate so many parents to ask the advice of friends or to buy a parenting
book to look for solutions? The answer is complex and multifaceted
and slightly different for each one of us. It might be linked to any or all of
the following: **the powerful feelings children being challenging and pushing
limits bring up in parents**;...

Cooper, A., & Redfern, S. (2015). Reflective parenting: A guide to understanding what's going on in your child's mind. Routledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not expressed very well. Maybe some bracketing will help:

The powerful feelings [that] (children [being challenging and pushing limits]) bring up in
parents.

Or a change in word order:
When children are (being challenging) and (pushing limits), that may bring up powerful feelings in their parents. That may make parents ask the advice of friends or buy a parenting book.

Answer (score 2):

It's a complex sentence that could be rewritten as:

> The answer may be linked to the powerful feelings that children can evoke in their parents by their challenging behaviour and their attempts to to push the boundaries their parents impose.